# jQuery return only <li> element text

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have added an .on() function to my dynamically added list elements with jQuery. The problem I'm facing is that the button that triggers the click lives inside the dynamically added li elements and therefore

```
$(this).parent().text()
```

returns the text from the li element as well as the button's text.

See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TL5TR/

How can I get around this problem and only display the li text (without the button text)? Would I have to rework my code in a way that button will be placed outside the li tag?

**Update**

Before I accept one of these answers -- all of them which are working by the way, so thank you, can you also explain to me what are the pros/cons of using one method or the other - i.e. textNode vs span tag.

Comment: In terms of pros and cons I think both solutions are pretty comparable.  The only one span advantage I can think of is that if in the future you add additional elements, the `previousSibling` solution may break whereas the `span` solution will continue to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to add `span` around your text:

```
$('#list').append("<li><span>" + item + "</span><button class='clickme'>Click me</button></li>");
```

And then:

```
$(this).siblings("span").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `textNode` is the previous sibling of the clicked button you can use `previousSibling` property.

```
$("#list").on('click', 'button', function() {
    alert(this.previousSibling.nodeValue);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cZk8H/

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding text wrapped in a span. And you should easily address the sibling's value, later:

```
var array = ["First", "Second", "Third"];
$.each(array, function(index, item) {
          $('#list').append("<li><span>" + item + "</span><button class='clickme'>Click me</button></li>");
        });


$("#list").on('click', 'button', function() {
      alert($(this).siblings().text());
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TL5TR/1/

---

**PROS (of using span) :** Better Management of text inside the li. You actually refer to the content enclosed in the span always....

**PROS(of not using span) :** Lesser tags in the HTML that you need to take care of. Although in this case I would say it's more of a micro management to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = ["First", "Second", "Third"];
$.each(array, function(index, item) {
          $('#list').append("<li><span>" + item + "</span> <button class='clickme'>Click me</button></li>");
        });


$("#list").on('click', 'button', function() {
      alert($(this).parent().find("span").text());
    });
```

put the text in a span tag

http://jsfiddle.net/TL5TR/2/

Answer (score 0):

Or instead of separating it out, you could just do this:

```
var array = ["First", "Second", "Third"];
$.each(array, function(index, item) {
    $("<li>" + item + " <button class='clickme'>Click me</button></li>")
       .appendTo('#list')
       .on('click', function() { alert(item); });
});
```

Unless of course you are adding these some other way. Then I would use one of the other suggested answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the element and remove the children elements:

```
$(this).parent().clone().children().remove().end().text()
```